# Using Play's WS API to send gzipped request

Tags: scala, playframework, gzip

I'm using Play's WS API in Scala to make HTTP requests. I need to send a gzip post request and I'm having difficulty doing this right.

```
val compressedData = deflate(data).get
val request = (<requestHolder>).withHeaders("Content-Encoding" -> "gzip")
  .withHeaders("Content-Length" -> compressedData.size.toString).withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json")

val temp = getStringFromByteArray(compressedData)
request.post(temp).map { r =>
  if(r.status / 100 == 2) {
    r.json
  }
  else { ...} }
```

This is my gzip helper methods:

```
  def deflate(txt: String): Try[ByteArrayOutputStream] = Try {
    val outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val zipStream = new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream)
    zipStream.write(txt.getBytes)
    zipStream.close()
    outputStream
  }

  def getStringFromByteArray(stream: ByteArrayOutputStream): String = {
    Base64.encodeBase64String(stream.toByteArray)
  }
```

Comment: what's the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: I'm sending data and the client is an instance of Elasticsearch with http compression enabled. Elasticsearch is erroring on processing the request with "decompression failure (-3): not a gzip stream". So I'm assuming that it's a problem on my side.

Comment: your content-type should still represent the underlying form of the data

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry that was copy paste error to the question- it is set to "application/json".